# Deploy metadata from one org to another using apex

Tags: apex, deployment

I only want to deploy custom fields of an object from One Org to another Org using apex class.

Note: Both the orgs are not interlinked with each other.

Is it possible? If yes how?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to deploy using apex, rather than the provided tools?

Answer (score 1):

The [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm) makes use of web services and so can be called from Apex and used to do what you ask. See the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) for code and additional information and examples.

However, there are simpler ways to get what you want done (if you relax the need for this to be done via an Apex class), including the platform's built in [Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets.htm&language=en) an the [Ant-based Migration Tools](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool).